# How can I see the ingress endpoints of kubernetes?

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, minikube

I would like to know, which are the endpoints correctly configured for a certain ingress.

For instance I have the following ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dictionary
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dictionary.juan.com
    secretName: microsyn-secret
  backend:
    serviceName: microsyn
    servicePort: 8080
  rules:
    - host: dictionary.juan.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /synonyms/*
          backend:
            serviceName: microsyn
            servicePort: 8080
```

that is working the following service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: microsyn
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: microsyn
```

This service is exposing this deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: microsyn
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: microsyn
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: microsyn
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: microsyn
        image: microsynonyms
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

The application is a nodejs app listening on port 8080, that says hello for path '/', in a docker image I just created locally, that's the reason it has a imagePullPolicy: Never, it is just for testing purposes and learn how to create an ingress.

So I created the ingress from nginx-ingress and it is up and running with a nodeport for local environment test, later I will take it to a deployment with load balancer:

https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/complete-example

So I do the following:

`minikube service list`

`|---------------|----------------------|--------------------------------|
|   NAMESPACE   |         NAME         |              URL               |
|---------------|----------------------|--------------------------------|
| default       | kubernetes           | No node port                   |
| default       | microsyn             | No node port                   |
| kube-system   | default-http-backend | http://192.168.99.100:30001    |
| kube-system   | kube-dns             | No node port                   |
| kube-system   | kubernetes-dashboard | http://192.168.99.100:30000    |
| nginx-ingress | nginx-ingress        | http://192.168.99.100:31253    |
|               |                      | http://192.168.99.100:31229    |
|---------------|----------------------|--------------------------------|`

Brilliant I can do:

`curl http://192.168.99.100:31253/synonyms`

But then I get a:

```
<html>
  <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
  <body bgcolor="white">
    <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
    <hr><center>nginx/1.15.2</center>
  </body>
</html>
```

So the only nginx I have is the one from this minikube, and it is working fine. But I cannot see which are the endpoints configured for this ingress...

I see the logs that says:

```
2018/08/11 16:07:05 [notice] 117#117: signal process started
I0811 16:07:05.313037       1 event.go:218] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"dictionary", UID:"9728e826-9d80-11e8-9caa-0800270091d8", APIVersion:"extensions", ResourceVersion:"57014", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'AddedOrUpdated' Configuration for default/dictionary was added or updated
W0811 16:15:05.826537       1 reflector.go:341] github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/nginx-controller/controller/controller.go:413: watch of *v1.ConfigMap ended with: too old resource version: 56348 (56655)
```

So that means that the dictionary ingress has being processed without errors.

But then Why I get a 404?

Where can I see the endpoints that are configured for this ingress??

I would like to run a command that says nginx --> which endpoints are you listening to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But then Why I get a 404?

Ingress resources -- or certainly the one you showed in your question -- use virtual-host routing, so one must set the `host:` header when interacting with that URL:

```
curl -H 'host: dictionary.juan.com' http://192.168.99.100:31253/synonyms/something
```

I would have to look up the `path:` syntax to know if `/synonyms/*` matches `/synonyms`, which is why I included the slash and extra content in `curl`.

For interacting with it in a non-`curl` way, you can either change the `host:` in the `Ingress` to temporarily be 192.168.99.100 or use [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) to create a local nameserver where you can override `dictionary.juan.com` to always return `192.168.99.100`, and then Chrome will send the correct `host:` header by itself.

> Where can I see the endpoints that are configured for this ingress??

The question is slightly inaccurate in that `Endpoint` is a formal resource, and not related to an `Ingress`, but the answer is:

```
kubectl get endpoints microsyn
```

> I would like to run a command that says nginx --> which endpoints are you listening to?

First, look up the name of the nginx-ingress Pod (any one of them should do, if you have multiple), and then look at the `nginx.conf` from the Pod to know exactly what rules it has converted the `Ingress` resource into:

```
kubectl exec $ingress_pod cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Comment: This is pretty accurate answer, although I found out that the pod of my nginx does not have any of the routes I expected to have, now I can take a look there to know if things are done correctly, thanks for this guide.